# Calculating an explicit Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I am trying to calculate the Radon-Nikodym derivative, $\frac{dP*}{dP}$, given $\{W_t,0\leq t\leq 3\}$ with $W_0=0$ being a Brownian motion under probability measure $P$, and $W_t^*=W_t+.04t$ being a Brownian motion under probability measure $P^*$. I am given the discrete values of $W_t$, which are $W_1=-0.23, W_2=0.35,W_3=0.71$

In the previous part, I derived the explicit formula for the Radon-Nikodym derivative, however it was in terms of stochastic integrals and I'm not sure how to go about calculating the explicit value of the derivative. I know I can easily plug in the values of $W_t$ to get the values of $W_t^*$, but I don't really have an idea on where to go next.

Comment: This seems tailor-made for the [Girsanov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem) (with $X_t = -0.04W_t$)

Comment: @Brianmoehring This may be a dumb question, but why is $X_t=-0.04W_t$? When we were learning the Girsanov theorem, we described $W_t^*=W_t+\int_0^t \theta_udu$ where $\theta_t$ was adapted to the natural filtration. If these are the same adapted process, then wouldn't $X_t=.04$? Or is this a different adapted process?

Comment: I was just trying to make my comment compatible with the wikipedia page.  In your case we'd have $\theta_t = 0.04$ but if we use the version I linked, we'd want $Y_t = W_t$ and $X_t$ defined such that $[Y,X]_t = -0.04t$.  If you are more comfortable with a different version of Girsanov, by all means use it instead.

Comment: @BrianMoehring That makes sense, thank you so much! I think I'm finally starting to get the hang of Girsanov's theorem. So what I'm getting now is that $\frac{dP^*}{dP}=exp(-.04W_t-\frac{1}{2}(.04)^2t)$. As for calculating the explicit value of the Radon-Nikodym derivative itself, am I meant to simply plug in the values for $0,1,2,$ and $3$ and sum up each respective value?

Comment: I don't know about the given values, since you have only said you're given a few values of $W_t$ (btw, did you mean to have two different $W_1$?) and not what you're supposed to do with them.  What precisely is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah, my fault, the two different $W_1$'s was a typo on my end, should be fixed now. The problem asks me to "Find the value of the Radon-Nikodym derivative given the information provided by the three measurements," and that the answer should be an explicit number. I guess I'm just not really sure how I should be utilizing the discrete values of $W$ that are given